# RecyclerView Checkboxes lose value when layout switched

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-checkbox

I'm having trouble with my recyclerview. It seems whenever the phone is turned into landscape mode, or the layout is switched in the app, the previously selected checkboxes are not restored.

EDIT------------------------------------------------

Here is my recycler adapter:

```
public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout) {
    mContext = context;
    this.workout = workout;
}
// INITIALIZE HOLDER
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    final Workout isCheck = workout.get(position);
    holder.check1.setChecked(isCheck.isCheck1());


    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheck.setCheck1(isChecked);
        }
    });

}
```

This is where the adapter is set in each fragment class(this is in the onCreateView):

```
//RECYCLERVIEW
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerWed);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getWedWorkout()));
return view;
}
```

And here is where the fragments are set up:

```
public class WorkoutDaysActivity extends BaseActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_days);
    mToolBar = activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Workout");

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    this.addPages(vp);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vp);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(listener(vp));

}

//ADD ALL PAGES
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
    MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String workout = intent.getStringExtra("workout");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("workout", workout);

    MondayFragment mondayFragment = new MondayFragment();
    mondayFragment.setArguments(args);
    adapter.addPage(mondayFragment);
    WedFragment wedFragment = new WedFragment();
    wedFragment.setArguments(args);
    adapter.addPage(wedFragment);
    FridayFragment fridayFragment = new FridayFragment();
    fridayFragment.setArguments(args);
    adapter.addPage(fridayFragment);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, the fragments get re-created everytime you close it and reopen it, the same happens when the orientation changes. To answer your question, yes! There are some ways to solve that, I would use SharedPraferences to save the state of the checkbox and restore it back to that state. Example?

```
    int firstSecondOrThird; //first page, second page or thrid page.

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout, int thePosition) {
        mContext = context;
        this.workout = workout;
        this.firstSecondOrThird = thePosition;
    }


    final SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
        //...
        prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("ehehehe", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false)); //restore the state of the CheckBox
        isCheck.setCheck1(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false)); //not sure what's this just copying from you ^^


        holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                isCheck.setCheck1(isChecked);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, isChecked).apply(); //save the CheckBox's state
            }
        });

    }
```

And initiate it like this:

```
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerWed);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getWedWorkout(), 1)); //in your first page

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerWed);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getWedWorkout(), 2)); //in your second page, and 3 or the third
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked, you need help with anyhting else? I'm bored

Comment: Thanks, that works, unfortunately because I have an expandable list view, and every option sends the app to the same tablayout with 3 tabs and each one having recycler view, it saves the checked ones for every fragment and every expandable list view option LOL.. any easy way to fix this?

Comment: No just a single viewholder, each recycler view uses the same one, just with different data, I send a bundle from my expandable list view, then where the fragments are created, i attach the bundle, then in each fragment i check which string was sent from expandable list view and use a switch statement to set the data

Comment: Okay can you post your adapter's constructor and how you are iniciating the adapter for each list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120282/discussion-between-lbj33-and-kurlicue).

Comment: Edited my original post

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to *retain the fragment instance*?

Check out the Android Dev Reference here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated